# posix_fadvise not working

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I have following code for opening all files:

```
int ret= open(zFile, flags, mode);
posix_fadvise (ret, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_RANDOM);
```

and posix_fadvise return 0 means success.

But it is not working correctly.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Strace is showing that the read done by the program is 
29088 bytes.

I used following command to calculate read from strace log

```
cat fadvise3.log | grep read | awk '{SUM+=$NF} END {print SUM}'
```

But iotop is showing that program has read about `2.5 MB.`

1. Is there a way I can know why it is reading  that much ?
2. Why iotop O/p is not matching with strace?
3. Why posix_fadvise (ret, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_RANDOM); is not working?
4. How can I disable read ahead for a process?

More details about read:
I am using sqlite library. and modified their function posixOpen to open a database. Read is done by sqlite.

Comment: Show us how you made the read. What do you mean with "it is not working correctly"? You just gave an hint to the OS about how you'll read the file.

Comment: @Adriano I had updated question with more details. What I am tried is to modified sqlite library posixopen call to add fadvise call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk read are done in disk block, this is a hardware limit, `POSIX_FADV_RANDOM` can't change that. If you read less then a block, you still have to pay the cost of that block.

Even so, `posix_fadvise`, as its name suggest, is just an advise to the kernel. A hint. Not a strict rule.

Comment: yes - it's the read done by the block layer. Note some raid card have on card readahead, hd have on disk cache. This is the best number you can get, but still not the real (hardware) read size.

Answer (score 3):

posix_fadvise will change the amount of read-ahead done *internally* in the kernel. It will not change the parameters a user-space application will pass to the read syscall. Thus you should not except that the parameters to the read syscalls will be any different when running it under strace.

Comment: I think my question description was not descriptive.Sorry for that. 
I am not running process inside strace. I am using iotop to measure read done by the process. I just attached strace to the process to verify is it matching with iotop and checked there is lot of difference b/w strace calculation and iotop calculation. 
I think answer from J-16 SDiZ may help me  to understand that diff.

Comment: Is there a way I can force read only required bytes I asked ?